# How do I list all users logged into Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, users

I use Gnome 3 and I have 2 desktops on it (2 users). Both of them are logged simultaneously and I navigate between desktops via Switch User option.

Sometimes, my other desktop won't load and I kill that user via `pkill -KILL -u username` command.

Now, I have more users but when I try `who` the console does not display other user. How can I see which users are logged into Gnome3 in the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:`ck-history --last`

This will include users who logged in via Gnome / GDM.  I found that commands like 'who', 'w', 'finger', 'last' only display terminal logins.

Comment: this actually works. Thanks. But the better command is `ck-history --last | more` as there are MANY data in it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following command:

```
sudo who -u -d
```

This should show you all logged in users - even the ones with dead processes.

Comment: I noticed that only the sudo user shows up in the `who` command. Even if I login as the other user and type `who`, only the sudo user appears.

Answer (score 0):

A logged in user will be running a process `gnome-session-ctl`.  Assuming that keeps running when you switch user, so you can look for that and get its owner:

```
pgrep gnome-session-c | xargs ps u | awk '/gnome-session-ctl/{print $1}' | grep -v gdm
```

Note:

- Linux stores only 15 chars of the process executable name directly with the process, hence pgrep can only look for `gnome-session-c`.  Anything longer needs a lookup; `ps` gives us that lookup - and the user name.
- gnome-session-ctl can appear as an argument to another process, so casually grepping `ps` for `gnome-session-ctl` without additional filtering may get false positives.
- Excluding the `gdm` user is a safety net just in case gdm ever starts a ctl process - you probably don't want to kill gdm!  Maybe overkill but better safe than sorry.
- Note that you could also go after some other gnome process such as `gdm-x-session` or `gdm-session-worker`.